# Maximum Number of Points on a n x n lattice Grid satisfying a non-parallel condition

Tags: combinatorial-geometry

After playing the game Pythagorea, my friend came up with a really interesting question:

> For a positive integer $m$, pick $m$ points on a $n \times n$ lattice grid such that we cannot draw two segments (out of the picked points) that are parallel. What is the maximum value of $m$?

Any ideas or comments about this problem are appreciated.

Comment: Do three collinear points count for parallel segments? It looks as though the answer is yes. If so, you can't do better than $n+1$.

Comment: I also think we can't do better than $\frac{1}{2} ( 1 + \sqrt{32n - 31} )$ since there are $4n-4$ possible slopes.